# why am i getting error for parameters of class function? "no matching function for call" C++

Tags: c++

error: no matching function for call to 'Player::setX(int&, bool&)'

in main:

```
    //player
    pc.setX(pc.x, *actions); //actions is an arr of input possibilities.
    pc.setY(pc.y, *actions);
```

in player.h:

```
  public:
  int x = 1, y = 1;
  int setY (int y, int *actions);
  int setX (int x, int *actions);
```

secondary question: is it possible to pass x/y as a struct instead of individually?

all the code that should be necessary afaik:

```
    bool actions[10]; //"up", "down", "left", "right", "skill1", "skill2", "skill3", "skill4", "skill5", "interact",
Player pc; //object creation

//player
pc.setX(pc.x, *actions);
pc.setY(pc.y, *actions);



#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
  class Player
  {
    public:
      int x = 1, y = 1;
      int setY (int y, int *actions);
      int setX (int x, int *actions);
    private:

  };
#endif //
```

Comment: Don't put the variable type as a comment. Include the declaration as it is in the code. Make a [mcve]. It looks like you're trying to pass a `bool` instead of an `int*`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Show us a bit more code (the declaration of actions at least) and we can help you.

Comment: `actions` is a `bool[]` array, where `*actions` accesses the 1st `bool` in the array.  You are trying to pass a single `bool` where an `int*` pointer is expected, that is what the error is telling you. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? As for x/y, of course you can pass a `struct` instead, why would you think otherwise?

Comment: im trying to pass the int address of the bool array. also I tried using a struct early and could figure it out. Guess i'll revisit that

Comment: There is no `int` address for a `bool` array.

Comment: an address is always an  int isnt it?

Comment: If you are trying to pass the array itself to the functions, then change the parameters from `int*` to `bool*`, and then change `*actions` to just `actions` when calling them.  And then get yourself [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) that explains how pointers actually work.

Comment: An address is an integer, but rarely an `int`. If you managed to convert (cast) the `bool[]` to an `int*` your function would be in trouble. It'd try to read `int` values from the decayed array which is usually much larger than `bool` values. You'd probably end up reading 4 or 8 `bool`s as one `int`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Yes you can pass both variable in a struct as:

        typedef struct { int x, int y}sXYInfo;
        class Player
        { public:
          sXYInfo m_sxy;
          int setXY (sXYInfo sxy , int *actions);
         };
and when calling use below, as you are passing array as a pointer:
    pc.setXY(pc.m_sxy, actions);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The main problem in OP:s code is that he/she passes a `bool` instead of an `int*` to the `actions` argument.